# C# simple multithreading

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I'm quite new to multithreading and today I ran into this strange problem. I followed some online tutorials and it seemed to me that what I'm doing is the correct.

So I got this code:

```
GrammarThreading gThread = new GrammarThreading(this, grammar);
Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(gThread.threadUnloadGrammar));
```

with it I want to move grammar unloading to another thread, since it takes a couple of seconds. This is how the class of GrammarThreading looks like:

```
public class GrammarThreading
{
    public MainWindow window { get; set; }
    public Grammar grammar { get; set; }

    public GrammarThreading(MainWindow _window, Grammar _grammar)
    {
        window = _window;
        grammar = _grammar;
    }

    public void threadUnloadGrammar()
    {
        window._recognizer.UnloadGrammar(grammar);
    }
}
```

However, I debugged the code and threadUnloadGrammar() method seems never to be called. I've got no idea what could the problem be so any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: Are you calling `thread.Start()` anywhere?

Comment: :-) If you're using .NET Framework 4, there's also a `TaskFactory` class in the `System.Threading.Tasks` namespace that's worth looking into.  It's a very similar creature and has small trade-offs either way, but does allow a nice fluent syntax for chaining events together.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to call `thread.Start()` to start the thread.

On another note, it seems `threadUnloadGrammar()` uses a variable of type `MainWindow`. Not sure what `MainWindow._recognizer.UnloadGrammar` does exactly, but make sure it doesn't access any UI elements in there, unless it uses [`Control.Invoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx) for that.

Answer (score 4):

You need to call [Thread.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.start.aspx) to schedule your thread for execution.